# Creating a 2d array by decoding json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I have the following json:

```
[ { "location" : { "LocationName" : "Location1",
    "id_Location" : "1"
} },
{ "location" : { "LocationName" : "Location2",
    "id_Location" : "2"
} },
{ "location" : { "LocationName" : "Location3",
    "id_Location" : "3"
} },
```

I need to decode this json and create an 2d array like below,

```
locationArray = [
[{
  LocationName: 'Location1',
  id_Location: '1'
}, {
  LocationName: 'Location2',
  id_Location: '2'
}, {
  LocationName: 'Location3',
  id_Location: '3'
}],
[]
];
```

I am working with  angular.js , so using an `angular.foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.

```
var a =[ { "location" : { "LocationName" : "Location1",
        "id_Location" : "1"
      } },
  { "location" : { "LocationName" : "Location2",
        "id_Location" : "2"
      } },
  { "location" : { "LocationName" : "Location3",
        "id_Location" : "3"
      } }];

var locationArray = a.map(function(o) { return o.location; });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
var jsonArr = [];    
angular.forEach(yourJson.location, function(val, iter){
    var actLocation = {locationName: val.LocationName, id_location: val.id_location};
    jsonArr.push(actLocation);
});
```